# What is this Ruby Code doing?

Tags: ruby

Can someone help me figure out what this Ruby code is doing?

```
def initialize(board = nil)
  @board = board || Array.new(9, " ")
end

def won?
  WIN_COMBINATIONS.detect do |combo|
    position(combo[0]) == position(combo[1]) && position(combo[1]) == position(combo[2]) && position_taken?(combo[0])
  end
end

def position(location)
  @board[location.to_i]
end

WIN_COMBINATIONS = [
  #horizontal
  [0,1,2],
  [3,4,5],
  [6,7,8],
  #vertical
  [0,3,6],
  [1,4,7],
  [2,5,8],
  #diagonal
  [0,4,8],
  [6,4,2]
]
```

I specifically do not understand the following:

1. How is `won?` method operating?
2. How is `won?` using `position` method?

Comment: where is the `won?` method?

Comment: Apparently, the code is part of a larger class, but you are only showing an excerpt that is not runnable on its own. In order to get help, you have to provide a [mcve].

Comment: def won?
     WIN_COMBINATIONS.detect do |combo|
       position(combo[0]) == position(combo[1]) && position(combo[1]) == position(combo[2]) && position_taken?(combo[0])
     end
   end

Comment: See the documentation of [Enumerable#detect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect).

Comment: What is `position_taken?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code defines `WIN_COMBINATIONS` for tic-tac-toe. There are three ways to win horizontally, by putting 3 of your mark into the same row. There are three ways to win vertically, by putting 3 of your mark into the same column. There are two ways to win diagonally, by putting 3 of your marks to the same diagonal.

To determine whether a game is `won`, you need to get all the winning combinations and check whether the game is `won`, that is, there are three similar marks for any of the `combo`s.

`position` returns the value of the `board` on a specific `position`. `won` calls `position` by passing the desired indexes for a `combo`.

Answer (score 1):

> how is the `won?` method operating?

It is searching current `@board` through all possible `WIN_COMBINATIONS`, one by one, until it founds a winning position.

That's what `detect` is for; from the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect):

> Passes each entry in enum to *block*. Returns the first for which
>   *block* is not false.

So if first winning position doesn't match (i.e. condition inside `detect` *block* is `false`) it moves to the next one; it stops looking as soon as it finds a match (i.e. condition is `true`).

> How `won?` is using `position` method?

`position` returns the value of `@board` at a given `location`, where `location` is the index in `@board` array.

`won?` compares if every `location` in a winning combination (i.e. every value in `combo`) has the same value, and checks whether that value is blank or not (i assume that `position_taken?` does that check).

For example, consider a board with the following position:

```
 x | o | o 
---+---+---
 x | x | x
---+---+---
 o |   |
```

Which translates to `@board` content as:

```
 ["x", "o", "o", "x", "x", "x", "o", " " ," "]
#  0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
```

*Second lines indicates the* index *of each position in the array; i include it just for reference.*

So, when `won?` is called, it iterates `WIN_COMBINATIONS`, like so:

```
# First iteration
combo = [0,1,2]

position(0) == position(1) && position(1) == position(2) && position_taken?(0)
```

Which translates into:

```
@board[0] == @board[1] && @board[1] == @board[2] && position_taken?(0)
```

And then to:

```
"x" == "o" && "o" == "o" && true
```

This will evaluate to`false` since first condition is `false` (when using `&&` operator **all** conditions need to be `true` in order to return `true`).

So, since it is `false`, the iteration continues:

```
# Second iteration
combo = [3,4,5]

position(3) == position(4) && position(4) == position(5) && position_taken?(0)
```

Which translates into:

```
@board[3] == @board[4] && @board[4] == @board[5] && position_taken?(3)
```

And then to:

```
"x" == "x" && "x" == "x" && true
```

This will evaluate to `true` since **all** combinations are `true`, so the iteration will stop and `win?` will also evaluate to `true`<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> *Notice that, [as pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44613709/what-is-this-ruby-code-doing/44614660?noredirect=1#comment76250057_44614660) by [engineersmnky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1978251/engineersmnky), `won?` will return a* truthy value *of `[3,4,5] (Array)` not `true (TrueClass)`.*

Comment: Nice explanation although technically `won?` will return a truthy value of `[3,4,5]` (`Array`) not `true` (`TrueClass`). Since this method ends with a `?` suggesting a boolean response `Enumerable#any?` would be a better option than `Enumerable#detect` and would response appropriately

Comment: @engineersmnky You're right, good observation, `detect` returns either the matched element or `nil`. I'll add a note in the answer. Thank you!